# Different results when encrypting with Common Crypto and Crypto++ with AES

Tags: c++, objective-c, encryption, crypto++, commoncrypto

I get different results when encrypting the same file (binary data) with the same key with Apple's Common Crypto and Crypto++. The algorithm I'm using is AES.

Here's the code in Objective C using Common Crypto:

```
void FileUtil::writeToFileEncrypt(string fileName, const void *data, int size, string key, int *sizeOut)
{
    int numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];

    if (key.length() > 32)
    {
        key = key.substr(0, 32);
    }

    memcpy(keyPtr, key.c_str(), sizeof(keyPtr));

    if (key.length() < 32)
    {
        for (int i = key.length(); i < 32; i++)
        {
            keyPtr[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    size_t bufferSize = size + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      data, size, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        cout << "encrypt success" << endl;
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
    myfile.write((const char *)buffer, numBytesEncrypted);
    myfile.close();

    free(buffer);

    *sizeOut = numBytesEncrypted;
}
```

Here's the code in C++ using Crypto++

```
void EncryptUtils::encrypt(string fileName, unsigned char *chars, string key, int *length, int dataLength)
{
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"0000000000000000";

    char keyPtr[32 + 1];

    if (key.length() > 32)
    {
        key = key.substr(0, 32);
    }

    memcpy(keyPtr, key.c_str(), sizeof(keyPtr));

    if (key.length() < 32)
    {
        for (int i = key.length(); i < 32; i++)
        {
            keyPtr[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    keyPtr[32] = '\0';

    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption((unsigned char *)keyPtr, 32);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    int newBufSize = (sizeof(unsigned char *) * dataLength) + 32;
    unsigned char *newBuf = (unsigned char *)malloc(newBufSize);
    CryptoPP::ArraySink *arraySink = new CryptoPP::ArraySink(newBuf, newBufSize);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, arraySink, CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING);
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(chars), (unsigned int)dataLength);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    *length = arraySink->TotalPutLength();

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
    myfile.write((const char *)newBuf, *length);
    myfile.close();
}
```

I need to get both of them to produce the same results. Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: If you are working in C++, why are you using `malloc`? You should be using `new`; or use a `auto_ptr` or a standard container like `vector` or `array`.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't be using malloc. I used malloc out of habit because I come from a C background and am new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The "Objective-C" version is not written in Objective-C, it is in C++. the actual encryption used `CCCrypt` which is plain "C".
2. The "Objective-C" version has no `iv` supplied so it defaults to all zeros. The C++ version supplies an `iv` of ASCII "0" characters, that is not the same as all zero data.This is probably the error.
3. Provide input and output hex data dumps for each including key, iv, data in and data out immediately prior to and after the encryption calls.

Comment: The iv was the main problem. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
memcpy(keyPtr, key.c_str(), sizeof(keyPtr));
```

It tries to copy 33 bytes. I think you need something like:

```
size_t ksize = std::min(sizeof(keyPtr), key.size());
assert(ksize == 16 || ksize == 24 || ksize == 32);
```

### -----

In general, the design is wrong:

```
keyPtr[32] = '\0';
```

Keys are binary, and not ASCII strings. If you are using passwords, then its still wrong since you should be using a KDF to digest the password into a suitable key.

### -----

The common Crypto code lacks an IV and may not use the same padding as the Crypto++ example.

### -----

The use of AES appears to be wrong. It appears your are operating the cipher in ECB mode, so its only providing confidentiality ***if*** the data is less than a block size. Its subject to reordering and manipulation, so its not providing authenticity assurances. You should use an [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) like [EAX](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Eax_mode), [GCM](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gcm_mode) or [CCM](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ccm_mode) mode.

Since Common Crypto is lame (it does not provide authenticated encryption modes) and Crypto++ provides everything you need (and it runs nearly everywhere), you should use Crypto++ and an authenticated encryption mode.

Comment: Common Crypto defaults to CBC, in order to use ECB that option must be explicitly set which it is not. Note that while a poor coding choice '\0' is 0 not '0'.  While it is unfortunate that Common Crypto does not support EAX, GCM or CCM mode unless those modes are necessary Common Crypto is the best solution, it is supplied by Apple, works, it well understood in the iOS community and does not require compiling Crypto++.

Comment: @ Zaph - thanks for the Common Crypto correction. Crypto++ allows a single set of sources, so I'm not sure its a benefit to re-implement with Apple's library which only runs on one platform. One implementations seems better than 4x implementations (Crypto++, iOS, Android, Windows). Plus, we know Apple's implementations has unfixed bugs. It cause a lot of problems with OpenSSL and ECDHE/ECDSA.

Comment: Please point to information on "Apple's implementations has unfixed bugs", I am interested in seeing them. Also it would be a huge plus if Crypto++ had a version that is available for php given that php padding is not PKCS#7 and a PITA.

Comment: @Zaph - see for example, [SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG) on the OpenSSL wiki. And don't forget about their [Goto Fail bug](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).  I even have open bug reports with them for defects in their security gear. They are not public yet.

Comment: Goto Fail was not in Common Crypto nor is the  SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG. Looking at the Crypto++ wiki it seems that GCC is required which no longer ships with Xcode.

Comment: @Zaph - regarding the PHP improvement, what do you need? We are adding features to Crypto++ at the moment (not the library proper as Wei Dai controls that). If we can work together, I might be able to help with the PHP padding issue (Crypto++ is one of my specialties). If we develop a set of patches, they will be made freely available on the Crypto++ wiki. As examples, see [Base64URLEncoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLEncoder) and [PEM Pack](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pem_pack).

Comment: php uses zero padding not PKCS#7 and this pops up often as an interoperability bug. For general use with iOS Crypto++ would have to compile with the LLVM compiler shipped with Xcode. If there were a compiled library I could easily recommend Crypto++. Keep in mind that most crypto questiopns in the iOS section of SO are by developers who have little to no knowledge about cryptography, shouldn't even be using it. Those who do know don't generally need help here. Hopefully you have looked at RNCryptor, it also supportrs several platforms.

Comment: One problem I have with many 3rd party libraries in C++ or JAVA, php and etc is that they lack complete descriptions of what is going on under-the-hood. Things like default padding of keys and ivs and data, how the iv is transported, rounds used by PBKDF2, etc. This makes it hard to be interoperable.

Comment: @Zaph - do you have an email address you feel comfortable sharing? You can reach me at noloader, gmail account. I want to get a wiki page up on PHP and mcrypt interop . Unfortunately, I know neither of them, so I need help.

Comment: @Zaph - *"If there were a compiled library I could easily recommend Crypto++"* - we maintain pages on iOS at [iOS (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Command_Line%29) and [iOS (Xcode)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Xcode%29). They also link to my GitHub, which has a prebuilt fat binary ready to go. The fat library links against `libc++` (LLVM), and not `libstdc++` (GNU).

Comment: OK, I found it after taking a couple of wrong turns the first, make that second, link is to code that will not compile, I finally found your Git Hub project with a decent enough ReadMe. But the search reminds me of the location of the demolition notice in *Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy*: "Down to the cellar, with a flashlight, in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.” The reason Open Source sucks (in general) is developers write great software but skip the documentation or even how to find it.